# App Programming Question: Converting Code and Project Folders for the Smartphone's OS Compatibility

Tags: android, iphone, cross-platform, compatibility

I was thinking about how does the *Angry Bird* game for the iOS successfully converted into an Android compatible version. Does it involve using Phonegap or something?

When making games for iOS, the programmer preferred XCode. For Android game app, the programmer preferred Eclipse IDE and a LibGDX engine library. Because of this, like *Angry Birds* for example, this game became compatible for the iOS, Android, and even on the desktop computer.

The question is...how does it work?

Comment: How does what work? Writing the same app for iOS, Android, and desktop computer?

Comment: Converting Xcode project into Android project and export is as APK before publish it on Google Play.

Answer (score 2):

Quote from http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/Guides/Application_Fundamentals/Building_Cross_Platform_Applications

> Rarely does an organization have the luxury of building mobile apps for a single mobile platform. The fact is, the smartphone and tablet space is dominated by three big platforms: iOS, Android and Windows. As such, **in order to reach users, apps must be designed and built for all three of them. Traditionally this means using each platform’s provided technology and SDK, i.e. Objective-C for iOS, Java for Android and .NET for Windows**. Most cross-platform mobile toolkits fall short in this space because they provide a lowest-common-denominator experience and prevent developers going “to the metal” on any given platform.

Totally googled it :)

Comment: Does Xamarin restricted to used C# programming language only instead of Java programming language?

Comment: I wasn't referencing the application. I was referencing the paragraph which states that in order to have your application published on multiple OS it must be written in the language that the OS can read. And Yes, from what i read, Xamarin is restricted to C#. I dont believe there is a single application that can perfectly convert ANY programming language you want to another. And IF there was, It would be worth an extremely large amount of money. There are language converters for languages with large similarities such as Java -> C# and vice versa.

Comment: Java and C# are kinda like counterparts. Java can be reliable for libraries, cool updates, and lets you display and set images and audio. C# is more reliable in Windows.

Comment: @DavidDimalanta, Mono also uses the C# syntax. Which works great on Linux as well.